# How to frame XPATH query inorder to extract model metaid

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2, xml-libxml, sbml

This is the head of the XML file I am using

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <sbml xmlns="http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level3/version1/core" level="3" version="1">
      <model metaid="metaid0" id="bind2_sbml">
        <listOfUnitDefinitions>
          <unitDefinition id="second_order_rate">
            <listOfUnits>
              <unit scale="0" kind="litre" multiplier="1" exponent="1" />
              <unit scale="-6" kind="mole" multiplier="1" exponent="-1" />
              <unit scale="0" kind="second" multiplier="1" exponent="-1" />
            </listOfUnits>
```

I tried using /sbml[@xmlns="http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level3/version1/core"]/model

as suggested by https://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/xpath_generator.html. But this doesn't work as can be checked using https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester

Comment: @kjhughes Updated the question.

Comment: Any tool that suggested that XPath shouldn't be trusted.  Your XML has namespaces.  See duplicate link for how to deal with namespaces in your XPath.

Comment: @kjhughes Done. Issue solved. Thanks